# HTML/Javascript component that allows users to select from list of items and order their choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to present a user with a list of items, allow the user to select the ones he wants, and order the ones he selected. I'm currently managing it with two list boxes - one of the available items and one of the chosen items - four buttons (left and right to move between the boxes and up and down to reposition items), and jquery.

Both the code and the current result look ugly.
I remember seeing a plugin (perhaps jquery) that could do this but I can't seem to locate it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sexyselect was actually not capable of doing what I wanted, at least not in any easy way. I discovered asmselect http://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/ which does exactly what I want very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sexyselect -

http://www.sexyselect.net